# How to resolve an invalid dataloader passed

Tags: pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

f"An invalid dataloader was passed to `Trainer.{trainer_fn}({prefix}dataloaders=...)`."
ValueError: An invalid dataloader was passed to `Trainer.validate(dataloaders=...)`. Either pass the dataloader to the `.validate()` method OR implement `def val_dataloader(self):` in your LightningModule/LightningDataModule

It seems like it should be easy, but it's been stumping me.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem when converting from pytorch_lightning to lightning 2.x. In my case, I had overlooked replacing the old pytorch_lightning libraries with the new lightning.pytorch in my data module script.

Check and make sure that you are consistently importing and using the new lightning libraries for both the model(LightningModule) and the data module (LightningDataModule).  Correcting this solved the problem for me.